# JAVA serialize map as list BUT only for a specific ObjectMapper

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is there a way to serialize my map to a json list but only for a specific ObjectMapper ?

I have added my custom serialize class with @JsonSerialize and it works fine but I want this only for a specific ObjectMapper.

- the first ObjectMapper must serialize my map to a json map as initially
- the second ObjectMapper must serialize my map to a json list use my custom @JsonSerialize

Is this possible ?

Comment: Hi Mike ,Your question is not clear what your are trying to do over here are you using two Object mapper objects for same map class one for json map and one for json list?

Comment: Sounds like a xy-problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What do you really want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this should be possible. You need to register a module for the second `ObjectMapper`.

```
final SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(Map.class, new YourCustomSerializer());
module.addDeserializer(Map.class, new YourCustomDeserializer());

objectMapper.registerModule(module);
```